# Python's robotparser ignoring sitemaps

Tags: python, robots.txt

I've the following robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images/
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

and the following robotparser

```
def init_robot_parser(URL):
    robot_parser = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
    robot_parser.set_url(urlparse.urljoin(URL, "robots.txt"))
    robot_parser.read()

    return robot_parser
```

But when I do a `print robot_parser` Above `return robot_parser` all I get is

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images/
```

Why is it ignoring the Sitemap line, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitemap is an extension to the standard, and robotparser doesn't support it.  You can see in [the source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/robotparser.py?view=markup) that it only processes "user-agent", "disallow", and "allow".  For its current functionality (telling you whether a particular URL is allowed), understanding Sitemap isn't necessary.

Comment: True, but i need to see if there are sitemaps specified in order to parse them. I guess I'll just have to open the robots through urlopen. Thanks.

Comment: Just for people coming here now and in the future, sitemap support will be coming in [3.8](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5db5c0669e624767375593cc1a01f32092c91c58)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Repply ( https://github.com/seomoz/reppy ) to parse Robots.txt - it handles sitemaps.

Keep in mind though, that in some cases there is a sitemap on the default location (/sitemaps.xml), and the site owners didn't mention it within robots.txt (for example on toucharcade.com)

I also found at least one site which has its sitemaps compressed - that is robot.txt leads to a .gz file.